# How is this JQuery Popup bug fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have an interesting problem with my JQuery Popup. On the nav, you can click "Login" or "Sign Up" and a popup will appear. On the bottom of each popup is a link to the other process. So on the "Login" popup, on the very bottom it says: "Not a member yet? Sign Up." I click on Sign Up, it closes the login popup and opens the sign up popup. However, for the signup popup this process only happens if the login popup opens first. I don't know why this bug is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

```css
/* font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* end of font */

/* clear settings */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */

#nav {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}
/* end of nav */

/* index.php */

#course_MainTitle {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 187px;
  top: 20px;
}
#nav_logo {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 188px;
  top: 9px;
}
/* Search Engine */

#search_engine {
  background: white;
  color: #353535;
  outline: none;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 210px;
}
#search_engine::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: #353535;
}
#search_engine:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  color: #353535;
  opacity: 1;
}
#search_engine::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: #353535;
  opacity: 1;
}
#search_engine:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #353535;
}
/* End of Search Engine */

/* Login & Sign Up */

#login_nav_div,
#signup_nav_div {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #353535;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: -66px;
  background: white;
  top: 6px;
}
#login,
#signup {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: 9px;
}
/* End of Login & Sign Up */

/* end of index.php */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hacked Genius</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='main.js'></script>

  <style>
    /***********************\

 Modal Module - Title CSS FTW

\***********************/
    .Modal {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: transparent;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .Modal .content {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 30%;
      width: 390px;
      padding: 50px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #fff;
      transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(0);
      z-index: 50;
    }
    .Modal .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      right: 8px;
      display: block;
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      padding: 2px;
      line-height: 18px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #C5C5C5;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .Modal .close:before {
      content: '\2715';
    }
    .Modal.is-visible {
      visibility: visible;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      transition: background .35s;
      transition-delay: .1s;
      z-index: 40;
    }
    .Modal.is-visible .content {
      transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(1);
      transition: transform .35s;
    }
    /* Model */
    #login_title,
    #signup_title {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 23px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      position: relative;
      top: -20px;
      left: 110px;
    }
    #signup_title {
      left: 80px;
    }
    #login_username,
    #login_password,
    #signup_username,
    #signup_password,
    #signup_email {
      outline: none;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      color: #353535;
      padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size: 16px;
      position: relative;
      left: -30px;
      width: 425px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    #login_username:focus,
    #login_password:focus,
    #signup_username:focus,
    #signup_password:focus,
    #signup_email:focus {
      border: 1px solid #4096ee;
    }
    #login_submit,
    #signup_submit {
      /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#4096ee+0,4096ee+100;Blue+Flat+%232 */
      background: #4096ee;
      /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4096ee 0%, #4096ee 100%);
      /* FF3.6-15 */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4096ee 0%, #4096ee 100%);
      /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4096ee 0%, #4096ee 100%);
      /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4096ee', endColorstr='#4096ee', GradientType=0);
      /* IE6-9 */
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 11px 12px 11px 12px;
      font-size: 22px;
      width: 445px;
      font-weight: normal;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      float: left;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: -28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #login_submit:focus,
    #login_submit:hover {
      background: rgb(37, 141, 200);
    }
    /* End of Model */
    /* Error Messages */
    #login_username_error,
    #login_password_error,
    #login_failed {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: #DD4B39;
      position: relative;
      left: -30px;
      top: -8px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: none;
    }
    /* End of Error Messages */
    /* $_SESSION["id"] set */
    #user_avatar {
      float: left;
      width: 28px;
      height: 28px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: relative;
      top: -2px;
      left: -10px;
    }
    #user_username {
      color: white;
      float: right;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 16px;
      position: relative;
      top: -31px;
      left: -220px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    /* Drop Down */
    .dropdown_content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      color: #555;
      border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
      border-top: none;
      min-width: 220px;
      /* left: 1250px;
  top: 47px; */
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 10;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      top: 44px;
      left: -125px;
    }
    .dropdown_content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .dropdown_content a:hover {
      color: #4096EE;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
      display: block;
    }
    #dropdown_caret {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: 135px;
    }
    #login_label {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
    }
    #login_remember,
    #login_label {
      position: relative;
      top: 25px;
      left: -30px;
    }
    #login_label {
      left: -52px;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      /* Konqueror */
      -moz-user-select: none;
      /* Firefox */
      -ms-user-select: none;
      /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
      user-select: none;
      /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              not supported by any browser */
    }
    a #forgot_password {
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      position: relative;
      top: 25px;
      left: 120px;
    }
    a #forgot_password:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #login_line,
    #signup_line {
      background: #ccc;
      height: 1px;
      width: 490px;
      position: relative;
      top: 25px;
      left: -50px;
    }
    #signup_line {
      top: 78px;
    }
    #login_crossSection,
    #signup_crossSection {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: black;
      position: relative;
      top: 37px;
      left: 90px;
    }
    #login_crossSection a,
    #signup_crossSection a {
      color: #4096EE;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #login_crossSection a:hover,
    #signup_crossSection a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Login Popup -->

  <div id="Popup" class="Modal">
    <div class="content">
      <span id='login_title'> Welcome Back </span> 
      <br>
      <form action='' method='post'>
        <span id='login_failed'></span>
        <input id='login_username' placeholder='Username' name='login_username'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id='login_username_error'></span>
        <input id='login_password' placeholder='Password' name='login_password' type='password'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id='login_password_error'></span>
        <input type='button' value='Login' id='login_submit' onclick='checkErrors()'>
      </form>

      <!-- Remember Me -->

      <input type='checkbox' name='login_remember' id='login_remember'>
      <label for='login_remember' id='login_label'>Remember Me</label>

      <!-- End of Remember Me -->

      <!-- Forgot Password? -->
      <a href='#'> <span id='forgot_password'> Forgot Password? </span> 
      </a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- End of Forgot Password -->

      <!-- Cross Section -->

      <div id='login_line'></div>


      <span id='login_crossSection'> Not a member yet? <a href='#'> Sign Up </a> </span>

      <!-- End of Cross Section -->

      <span class="close"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- End of Login Popup -->
  
  <!-- Sign Up Popup -->
    <!-- Sign Up Popup -->
<div id="Popup2" class="Modal">
  <div class="content">
 <span id='signup_title'> Ready for awesome? </span> 
      <br>
      <form action='' method='post'>
        <span id='signup_failed'></span>
        <input id='signup_username' placeholder='Username' name='signup_username'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id='signup_username_error'></span>
        <input id='signup_email' placeholder='Email' name='signup_email'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id='signup_email_error'></span>
        <input id='signup_password' placeholder='Password' name='signup_password' type='password'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span id='signup_password_error'></span>
        <input type='button' value='Sign Up' id='signup_submit' onclick='checkErrors()'>
      </form>

      <!-- Cross Section -->

      <div id='signup_line'></div>


      <span id='signup_crossSection'> Already a member? <a href='#'> Login </a> </span>

      <!-- End of Cross Section -->

      <span class="close"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Sign Up Popup -->
  <!-- End of Sign Up Popup -->

 <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>
      <a href='index.php'> <span id='nav_logo'> Logo </span> 
      </a>

      <!-- Search Engine -->
      <input id='search_engine' placeholder='Search Courses'>
      <!-- End of Search Engine -->

      <!-- Sign Up -->
      <a href='#Popup2' class='button'>
        <div id='signup_nav_div'>
          <span id='signup'> Sign Up </span>
        </div>
      </a>

      <!-- End of Sign Up -->

      <!-- Login -->

      <a href='#Popup' class='button'>
        <div id='login_nav_div'>
          <span id='login'> Login </span>
        </div>
      </a>

      <!-- End of Login -->
      } ?>

    </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

    <script>
      $.fn.expose = function(options) {

        var $modal = $(this),
          $trigger = $('a[href="' + this.selector + '"]');

        $modal.on("expose:open", function() {

          $modal.addClass("is-visible");
          $modal.trigger("expose:opened");
        });

        $modal.on("expose:close", function() {

          $modal.removeClass("is-visible");
          $modal.trigger("expose:closed");
        });

        $trigger.on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $modal.trigger("expose:open");
        });

        $modal.on("click", function(e) {
          if ($(e.target).is($modal) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $modal.trigger("expose:close");
          }
        });

        return;
      }

       // Example Cancel Button

      $("#login_nav_div").click(function() {
        $("#Popup").expose();
      });

      $("#signup_nav_div").click(function() {
        $("#Popup2").expose();
      });

      $("#login_crossSection a").click(function() {
        $("#Popup").trigger('expose:close');
        $("#Popup2").trigger('expose:open');
      });

      $("#signup_crossSection a").click(function() {
        $("#Popup2").trigger('expose:close');
        $("#Popup").trigger('expose:open');
      });

      $(".cancel").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log('a')
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).trigger("expose:close");
      });

       // Example Callbacks
      /*
       $("#Popup").on("expose:opened", function() {

         alert("Modal Opened!");
       });

       $("#Popup").on("expose:closed", function() {

         alert("Modal Closed!");
       });
       */

      function checkErrors() {

        if ($("#login_remember").is(":checked")) {
          var checked = 1;
        } else {
          checked = 0;
        }

        var login_username_val = $("#login_username").val().length;
        var login_password_val = $("#login_password").val().length;

        var login_username = $("#login_username").val();
        var login_password = $("#login_password").val();

        if (login_username_val < 1) {
          $("#login_username_error").show().text("Username Required");
          $("#login_failed").hide();
          $("#login_username").css("border", "1px solid #DD4B39");
        } else {
          $("#login_username_error").hide();
          $("#login_username").css("border", "");
        }

        if (login_password_val < 1) {
          $("#login_password_error").show().text("Password Required");
          $("#login_failed").hide();
          $("#login_password").css("border", "1px solid #DD4B39");
        } else {
          $("#login_password_error").hide();
          $("#login_password").css("border", "");
        }

        if (login_password_val > 0 && login_username_val > 0) {
          $.post("check.php?checked=" + checked, {
            username: login_username,
            password: login_password
          }, function(data) {

            if (data == "Login Worked") {
              location.reload();
            }

            if (data == "Login Failed") {
              $("#login_failed").show().text("Login Failed");
            }
          });
        }

      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMhunter was not far... It's an initialisation thing.
I noticed that the "not appearing popup" was triggered... But didn't have the ".is-visible" class.

I played around a little... And found it:

```
  $("#login_crossSection a").click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked signup from login");
    $("#Popup2").expose();                  // Added
    $("#Popup").trigger('expose:close');
    $("#Popup2").trigger('expose:open');

  });

  $("#signup_crossSection a").click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked login from signup");
    $("#Popup").expose();                   // Added
    $("#Popup2").trigger('expose:close');
    $("#Popup").trigger('expose:open'); 
  });
```

Added these two lines... And it work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems u need to call make both popups call `expose()` before trigger events on them.

In ur code   ur popup modals are initialised (call expose()) only when user click on 'Login' or 'sign up' buttons.

One simple solution is just do the initialization when document is ready:

Just Change:

```
$("#login_nav_div").click(function() {
        $("#Popup").expose();
    });

    $("#signup_nav_div").click(function() {
        $("#Popup2").expose();
    });
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Popup").expose();
 $("#Popup2").expose();
})
```